# Login and password

Tags: 16.04

I have a problem with the screen going grey with only the cursor there; after login.  When I attempt to into the system through alt F2 I am asked for my username and password.  After typing it in, it comes back to say that it is wrong, but I know they are correct.  I am not very knowledgeable regarding computers.

Comment: My guess is there is a problem with graphics driver/adapter for the first login. I would say if computer says that login is incorrect, than it must be incorrect. Is it possible that you have a different keyboard layout when you press Alt-F2? That would explain why you can enter right credentials in graphic login and you cannot repeat that in text mode. You cannot see what is being entered when you type in password. If keyboard layout is different you do not see that wrong characters are entered in. Try to type in the password in the username to see it is correct.

Comment: Nothing has changed in the past few years on my keyboard.  I can actually log in as per normal (and the pc does tell me when I enter it wrongly), but after logging in the screen goes grey

Comment: Is there a way I can get past the login and password or at least renew them?

Comment: What is the exact error message when you try to log in through Ctrl-Alt-F2? Are you sure you are typing your login name (not necessarily the same as the "full name" that's displayed in the GUI login)

Comment: Steeldriver,  I get past Ctrl-Alt-F2, but it does not want to accept my login name and password.  So, now I'm attempting to get past that without the login name